# Subsets of power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give examples of two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cap \mathcal P(A) \in B $ and $\mathcal P(A) \subseteq A \cup B$.

So I'm thinking that $A \cap \mathcal P(A)$ is just $A$. If we take $A = \{ 1,2 \}$, then $ \mathcal P (A) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}.$ So we take $B= \{  \{ 1,2 \}, 1\}$.

- Is this correct? If not, why?
- Is $\{  \{ 1,2 \}, 1\}$ a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$ or $\{  \{ 1,2 \}, \{1\}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct but your reasons are not.
Note that for $A = {1,2}$ you have $P(A)= \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ but it is not correct that $1$ is equal to $\{1\}$, one time its the element $1$ and the second is the element which is the set containing only $1$.

Also your second statement is obviously not correct because of that reason, for a set $C$ be a sub set of a set $D$, every element of $C$ must be also element of $D$ (and not element of element of $D$).

For your question, you can take $B = P(A)$, then you have because the former that $A\cap P(A) = \emptyset$ which is an element of $P(A)$ and therefore of $B$, and $P(A)\subseteq A\cup B $ trivially, simply since $A\cup B$ contains by defenition $B$ which is exactly $P(A)$.